# Show that there is a sequence in $M$ that converges to $x\in A$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> > Consider the sets $M:=(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{(1-2^{-n})e^{\pi i\ell/2^n}: \ell\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,2^{n+1}-1\right\}\right\})\cup\left\{0\right\}$ and $A:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert=1\right\}$. Show that for each $y\in A$, there is a sequence in M that converges to y.

Hm, I tried rather Long to find such a sequence but did not had success to construct one. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $y=e^{i\theta}$, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ choose $k_n\in\{0,\ldots,2^{n+1}-1\}$ so that

$$\frac{\pi k_n}{2^n}\le\theta<\frac{\pi(k_n+1)}{2^n}\;,$$

where $k_n+1$ is computed mod $2^{n+1}$. Consider the points $z_n=(1-2^{-n})e^{\pi ik_n/2^n}$.

In order to see what’s going on, it may possibly be helpful to regard $M\cup A$ as a circular analogue of the following subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Let $I=[0,1]\times\{0\}$. For $n\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}$ let

$$I_n=\left\{\left\langle\frac{k}{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right\rangle:k\in\{0,\ldots,2^n-1\}\right\}\;.$$

The desired subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is then $I\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}}I_n$.

Comment: Ist rather hard for me to understand that. How can I understand the inequality ?

Comment: And isn't there missing the factor $(1-2^{-n})$ for the $z_n$?

Comment: Look at $n=2$ as an example. $M$ has points $\frac34e^{\pi ik/4}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,7$. Draw the rays from $0$ through these $8$ points; they divide the plane into $8$ sectors. Exactly one of those sectors includes $y$; choose that one. For $n=3$ each of these sectors is cut in half, and again you choose the one that contains $y$. It’s like the bisection method on the real line. (Yes, I left off the radius factor when I wrote $z_n$.)

Comment: Great, I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mathfemi: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but how to Show formally that $\lim z_n=y$?

Comment: @mathfemi: It follows pretty easily from the fact that $1-2^{-n}\to 1$ and $\frac{\pi k_n}{2^n}\to\theta$. The latter is true because $0\le\theta-\frac{\pi k_n}{2^n}<\frac{\pi}{2^n}$ for each $n$.